# Cannot compare HTML string in karma/jasmine/PhantomJS test because of icon

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have test which (should) checks if element html rendered by my factory is correct. However, this element contains material icon and it seems to be impossible to compare its HTML in this test.

Simplified test case:

```
describe( 'Compile: ', function () {
  it( 'compare two html strings and should be equal', function () {
    var mockEl = $( '<i class="material-icons">&#xE24B;</i>' )
      ;
    expect( mockEl[0].outerHTML ).toBe(
      '<i class="material-icons">&#xE24B;</i>'
    );    
  } );
} );
```

In result I test throws error:

```
Expected <i class="material-icons"></i>' to be '<i class="material-icons">&#xE24B;</i>'.
```

This is how icon jQuery object `text` looks like in Chrome console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing it using the unicode value like the following

```
expect( mockEl[0].outerHTML ).toBe(
  '<i class="material-icons">\ue24b</i>'
);
```